# GitHub Pages with Jekyll only displaying bare html

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to make a website with Jekyll and GitHub pages but the example page only displays as bare html

[image: Output of my page]

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: In **_config.yml**, set `baseurl: /youreponame`

Comment: Changing the config.yml file worked